# Add a link to the Documentation page in the Documentation: Proposed Changes review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, documentation-proposals

Currently, it doesn't seem to be possible to get to the Documentation topic from the Documentation Review Queue:

> [image]
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/97118

For example, in the Suggested Edits review queue, clicking on the question title will bring you to the post:

> [image]

I think it would be more convenient if a link to the topic can be added in the review page. It would especially be useful if the particular example or topic is deleted and there's no way to find it.

Comment: It works _if the proposed change does not create the topic._ I've used it a few times myself. I don't have a source that this is the case. But, for example, [this review](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94600?filter-tags=regex#comments) lets you go straight to the topic if you click the title. On that note, this would be useful for topic creations in case the creation was incorrect.

Comment: We are looking into this. The tricky bit is that it's hard to show the topic before it's been created. Once the edit has been accepted, however, the link should be available for linking.

Comment: @JonEricson Hmm... perhaps for topics that don't yet exist, a "tentative preview" could be automatically generated in this situation?  Or perhaps the link to the original could be disabled when the topic doesn't already exist, with mouseover text like "This page has not yet been created." or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A link should now be available for newly created topics, once they are approved.